# Do questions about game soundtrack (lyrics etc.) belong here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

For instance, I'm intrigued by the lyrics in the song "Sorceresses" in the Witcher 2 game and would like to know what it means. Is this the right place to ask?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/20523/23

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that soundtrack questions are similar to this type of question:

> - Plot and characters in games

which are specifically mentioned in the FAQ. We have questions like the Portal 2 soundtrack question that badp linked above, questions about [game location](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16203/what-parts-of-fallout-new-vegas-are-based-on-the-real-world) ... there are even questions about [custom music within games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1575/custom-music-in-burnout-paradise) and [non-English lines in games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7452/the-meaning-of-the-german-words-in-commandos)*. Those all seem to be questions about the environment within games.

Having said that, I think the content of the question is still important. I think if you want to know **what the lyrics are**, that's a question that fits the site well: it's practical and answerable. If you want to know **what they mean**, that could possibly be the type of question where every answer is equally valid (and thus the question would likely be closed), unless someone were able to track down a post on an official site that said "This is why we chose those lyrics".

*note that the answer to this question turned out to be "they don't mean anything", but I think the type of question is more important than the actual example, as indicated in the [meta discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/are-questions-about-natural-languages-appropriate-specific-example-included). (If it helps, imagine that they asked "What are the Nazi soldiers saying in the original Castle Wolfenstein?")